# java error installing running elastic stack in Windows 10

Tags: java, elastic-stack

I try to run elastic stack in windows 10 but I get the error:

"warning: usage of JAVA_HOME is deprecated, use ES_JAVA_HOME"
"could not find java in JAVA_HOME at "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\bin\java.exe""

My java.exe is located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java.exe   which is slightly different than above but all of my other java programs seem to work.

How do I fix this so that Elastic Stack will work?

Comment: Note, JAVA_HOME should not include the exe in the path, it should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\bin\` If you are unsure how to set or change an environment variable then see here: https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: For some reason elasticsearch.bat tries to find JAVA_HOME inside of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\bin\java.exe when the path for JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin How do I fix this? Is there a file in the elasticsearch folder I need to alter so that it searches for JAVA_HOME in the right location?

Answer (score 1):

You'r facing this problem due to wrong java folder location. Change or move your java folder to program files/Java and updated java path to ur system path and this will solve your problem .. !! This worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

First chack your JAVA_HOME, it shoud point to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15"

if you open service.bat you will see elasticsearch use  %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe, so your JAVA_HOME shoud not have \bin part.

Comment: For some reason elasticsearch.bat tries to find JAVA_HOME inside of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\bin\java.exe when the path for JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin   
How do I fix this?  Is there a file in the elasticsearch folder I need to alter so that it searches for JAVA_HOME in the right location?

Comment: @Amrit Yes service.bat - But first check your  JAVA_HOME, elasticsearch use %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe for java, So your JAVA_HOME shoud not include \bin part it shoud point to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15  or change %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe in service,bat to %JAVA_HOME%\java.exe

Answer (score 0):

Try using the docker ELK Stack instead installing everything manually - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

And you can run this in a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) instance of [Fedora](https://www.osboxes.org/fedora/) or [Ubuntu](https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/) so that you don't break your windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have installed Java correctly. Set the JAVA_HOME variable to specify the path to Java in your Windows environment variables and add it to the PATH. If these didn't work, try the following way.

1-Go to C:\elasticsearch-version\bin 
2-Open elasticsearch-env.bat for Windows with a text editor 
3-Find the set JAVA_HOME variables and remove the extra "\bin" added to the JAVA path you defined.

This is because you define JAVA_HOME as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin". You can also solve the problem by removing the "\bin" here. However, this can cause other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I changed the content of elasticsearch-env.bat and it worked.

you can alter elasticsearch-env.bat file, change from

```
if defined ES_JAVA_HOME (
  set JAVA="%ES_JAVA_HOME%**\bin**\java.exe"
  set JAVA_TYPE=ES_JAVA_HOME
) else if defined JAVA_HOME (
  rem fallback to JAVA_HOME
  echo "warning: usage of JAVA_HOME is deprecated, use ES_JAVA_HOME" >&2
  set JAVA="%JAVA_HOME%**\bin**\java.exe"
  set "ES_JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"
  set JAVA_TYPE=JAVA_HOME
```

to

```
if defined ES_JAVA_HOME (
  set JAVA="%ES_JAVA_HOME%\java.exe"
  set JAVA_TYPE=ES_JAVA_HOME
) else if defined JAVA_HOME (
  rem fallback to JAVA_HOME
  echo "warning: usage of JAVA_HOME is deprecated, use ES_JAVA_HOME" >&2
  set JAVA="%JAVA_HOME%\java.exe"
  set "ES_JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"
  set JAVA_TYPE=JAVA_HOME
```